# ntpdate ignores my timezone

Tags: centos5, timezone, time-synchronization, ntpdate

I'm trying to set up time sync on a CentOS 5.5 VDS but can't figure out why it won't update to the correct timezone. e.g. After manually setting the correct date and time when I run this:

```
date && ntpdate au.pool.ntp.org && date
```

I get this:

```
Mon Oct 17 08:58:48 EDT 2011
16 Oct 17:58:01 ntpdate[14659]: step time server 202.60.94.11 offset -54048.345159 sec
Sun Oct 16 17:58:01 EDT 2011
```

`etc/localtime` has been replaced with a link to the `Australia/Melbourne` timezone file and `/etc/sysconfig/clock' has been edited accordingly. The server has been rebooted since those changes and appears to (at long last) be using the correct timezone, so why does ntpdate appear to be ignoring it?

Incidentally, `rdate` simply times out and I've yet to determine why. I also have the `ntpd` service installed but have it disabled until I get this issue sorted out.

Comment: Was your timezone overwritten by another one? Can you do "strace ntpdate au.pool.ntp.org", at the end you should see a line similar to "read(5, "\nCET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3\n", 4096)". What does it show for you?

Comment: @ott, it shows `read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3519` and I don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: No, it's the read() 2 lines beyond that

Comment: In the past I had time problems (on Debian/Ubuntu) when the /etc/localtime was a soft link. Some programs and chrooted software behaved strangely. From there on I make sure that this is a real copy and not a link.

Comment: My trace looks different, the read is followed by lseek() and another read(). What does "tail -1 /etc/localtime" tell you?

Comment: @mailq, I've also tried copying the timezone file directly to /etc/localtime bat that didn't make any difference.

Comment: @ott, "tail -1 /etc/localtime" gives `EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0`

Comment: My Melbourne has EST-10EST,M10.1.0,M4.1.0/3. Yours is like the file for New_York.

Comment: @ott, please post that as an answer. It appears ALL the timezone files on the server are the same. I've overwritten localtime with the file from a local machine and all is now well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Melbourne has EST-10EST,M10.1.0,M4.1.0/3. Yours is like the file for New_York.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I finally determined my /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Melbourne file was the same as New_York.

Once I had changed it by copying a Australia Melbourne file from another server, all was fine with time again.

Simple to just do the following to reinstall tzdata

```
sudo yum reinstall tzdata
```

Very annoying issue but all fixed after that.

Comment: That did indeed turn out to be the problem in my case, which ott's answer alerted me to, and I fixed it the same way as you did.

Answer (score 1):

on debian-based systems, run as root:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

And select your correct timezone.